# Ruby on Rails- Display Country Real Name with country-selector

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, country-codes

In my Rails application, I installed the following gems

```
gem 'countries'
gem 'country_select'
gem 'simple_form'
```

When a user signs up, they select a country (ex. United Kingdom)

on the User's Show page `

```
<%= @user.country %>` => Displays GB
```

My question is, how do I display United Kingdom as full name?

Comment: I haven't used the gem but what happens if you say `<%= @user.country.name %>`?

Comment: when type <%= @user.country.name %>, display got error undefined method `name' for "GB":String

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the countries gem's github page](https://github.com/hexorx/countries#country-select-helper):

> This gem automatically integrates with country_select. It will change its behavior to store the alpha2 country code instead of the country name.

Then, from `country_select`'s [github page](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select#getting-the-country-name-from-the-countries-gem)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Assuming country_select is used with User attribute `country_code`
  # This will attempt to translate the country name and use the default
  # (usually English) name if no translation is available

  def country_name
    country = ISO3166::Country[country_code]
    country.translations[I18n.locale.to_s] || country.name
  end
end
```

Comment: Note that you have to say `<%= @user.country_**name** %>` now.

Comment: i got same error when i type <%= @user.country.name %>, error was  undefined method `name' for "GB":String

Comment: @MarySmith It has to be `country_name`, not `country.name`.

Comment: after i change country_name, another error i got          undefined local variable or method `country_code' for #<User:0x007f9ee11e9bc8>

Comment: @MarySmith This looks like it's coming from somewhere else, are you saying `@user.country_code` anywhere in your code? Also, it's probably a good idea to provide some of your code in the original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64724/discussion-between-mary-smith-and-sebkomianos).

Comment: @MarySmith I am in the chat.

Comment: @MarySmith May i know how you managed to solve this problem. I realise that you might have come up with a solution on the chat

Comment: @Benjamin She never turned up. Are you having the same problem?

Comment: @sebkomianos We got it sorted. Thank you for your response.

Comment: The country_select documentation is awful. What is the answer to this question? I have the above method in my model and call it with "@widget.country_name" and get a "undefined local variable or method `country_code'" error.

Comment: @MSC If you are getting a `undefined local variable country_code` error, then you have `country_code` somewhere in your code (model or controller). Check it.

Comment: did you figure this out?  I have the same problem. The only place where my code has the words 'country_code' is inside the country_name definition (as set out above)

Comment: @Mel do you have both countries and country_select gems in your gemfile?

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss - yes

Comment: @Mel here is the solution I used. I could not get this one on this page to work either. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34560638/rails-4-country-select-simple-form/34915060#34915060 see the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

`@user.country` will return a country object, ie an instance of class Country.  When you put this inside the erb tag, it will have "to_s" called on it as rails tries its best to make a string out of an object.  If the class defines a to_s method, then this is what is returned - i'm guessing it does and this method returns the country code.

You need to call the .name method on the country to get the name:

```
<%= @user.country.name %>
```

Comment: Which gem are you using?  I assumed it was this one https://github.com/hexorx/countries but it sounds different.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is to do with a missing gem here.

For this to work in your User model:

```
def country_name
    country = ISO3166::Country[country_code]
    country.translations[I18n.locale.to_s] || country.name
  end
end
```

You need to have the ["countries" gem](https://github.com/hexorx/countries/) installed as well as the country_select gem.